# How does one open .LMF files in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, file-type

I am currently using Visual Studio Code with a virtual environment and would like to open some `.LMF` files containing data. I have found **Python LMF library** and have installed it with `pip` in the Visual Studio Code terminal (note: this library is written for python2 and I am running python3).

```
pip install pylmflib
```

It starts with the following message:

```
Collecting pylmflib
Downloading pylmflib-1.0.tar.gz (4.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.0 MB 6.8 MB/s
```

but then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylmflib
```

I took the exact same approach for another (non-related) library and that did properly install. Can someone please help me so that I can open my `.LMF` file?

Comment: if they haven't written a Python3 version you have to port the Python2 code yourself.

Comment: Just add the `pylmflib` directory from https://github.com/buret/pylmflib to your project

Comment: The above did not work well, but I have found an alternative, to at least make the library work. I made a backup of the library, unzipped the entire library to my documents folder and then I typed in (windows) command prompt: py C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w C:\Users\<username>\Documents\pylmflib\



The file however still not opens

Comment: the software was written for Python2, did not install because you have Python3, you need to port the lib, to get the code copy the repo source directory but still you might need to port a line or 2, that is what that script does and tells you where it can't do automatic